# Find an expression for the $nth$ composition of $T$ with itself $T ^ n$ $(x, y)$. $T (x, y) = (3x - y, 2y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $$T: \mathbb{R}^2 → \mathbb{R}^2$$ be the linear transformation defined by $$T (x, y) = (3x - y, 2y)$$

Find an expression for the $nth$ composition of $T$ with itself $T ^ n$ $(x, y)$.

I'm stuglying find $T^n$, my teacher told to consider the Base =
$$\{(1, 1), (0, 1)\}$$
and apply some change of base.

Can someone help me?

Hint: consider the base {(1, 1), (1, 0)} and apply some change of base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's see.  The matrix rel the standard basis would be $A=\begin{pmatrix}3&-1\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$.  The characteristic polynomial is $C(x)=(x-3)(x-2)$.  The eigenvalues are thus $3$ and $2$.  Note that $T(1,1)=2\cdot(1,1)$, and $T(1,0)=3\cdot(1,0)$.  Thus your hint asks you to consider a basis of eigenvectors.

This basis can be used to diagonalize the matrix.  That is, if we set $P=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$, then $P^{-1}AP=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&3\end{pmatrix}$.

Now figuring out the $n$-th power of a diagonal matrix is easy.  In this case it's just $\begin{pmatrix}2^n&0\\0&3^n\end{pmatrix}$.

And you should be able to convince yourself that $A^n=P\begin{pmatrix}2^n&0\\0&3^n\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}$.